# Create a devise fixtures user devise a password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, devise

I have a rails 5 app running the latest devise and I'd like to create valid users for testing with the fixtures, but I can't update the password as the way devise has users set up there is no passwords column in the users table.

Is there a way to set the fixture up to work around this and have a working user?

text/fixtures/users.yml:

```
jeremy:
  email: jeremy@someemail.com
  provider: facebook
  username: Jeremy
```

password: password

any test using that user returns:

```
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "password".
```

Comment: Try to use another tool and not yml. Something like `FactoryGirl`. Devise use BCrypt to encrypt the password.

Comment: The answer below from Alex Kojin worked and didn't require changing anything, Factory Girl looks interesting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare your test database.

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```